# how to implement a server on iPhone

Tags: ios

Assuming I have implement that : 
making my app as a server which means in safari I can connect to the app if I input http://url-link.

My question is : if I request http:// url-link/doc, and the server - that is my app can return the content in document directory.

I don't know how to write the web service in iPhone.

As I'm fresh to web service, can any one help me?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possibility: [Cocoa HTTP Server](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer). From the project's page:

> So with Apple's framework for an HTTP
>   server tucked under our arm we set out
>   to make our own. We wanted the
>   following:
>
> - Built in support for bonjour broadcasting
> - IPv4 and IPv6 support
> - Asynchronous networking using standard Cocoa sockets/streams
> - Digest access authentication
> - TLS encryption support
> - Extremely FAST and memory efficient
> - Heavily commented code
> - Very easily extensible

You can link this library from your app and effectively make it a mini-web server.

Comment: I also think the RoutingHTTPServer project is a great addition to this! https://github.com/mattstevens/RoutingHTTPServer